# Can I find server-side hard drive letter using node.js?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to find server side hard drive name like C:, D:, E:, etc using node.js?

Answer (score 2):

In windows, you can use this command `wmic logicaldisk get caption`.

In Nodejs, you can spawn a new process to this cammand.

```
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    function showLetter(callback) {
        exec('wmic logicaldisk get caption', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            if(err || stderr) {
                console.log("root path open failed" + err + stderr);
                return;
            }
            callback(stdout);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We built a module called [drivelist](https://github.com/resin-io-modules/drivelist) do to exactly this, and works in all major operating systems. In Windows, for example, you might get an output similar to this one:

```
[
    {
        device: '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0',
        description: 'WDC WD10JPVX-75JC3T0',
        size: '1000 GB'
        mountpoint: 'C:',
        system: true
    },
    {
        device: '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE1',
        description: 'Generic STORAGE DEVICE USB Device',
        size: '15 GB'
        mountpoint: 'D:',
        system: false
    }
]
```

Notice it lists both removable and non-removable drives, although you can distinguish between them by the `system` property.

Comment: Depending on your needs, `drivelist` may not work for you. Mountpoints don't show up for drives in software RAID on Windows and Linux. This literally lists physical drives, not necessarily mountpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js way:

```
import * as path from 'path';
const cwdOSRoot = path.parse(process.cwd()).root;
const fileOSRoot = path.parse(__dirname).root;
```

Important to note, one will get you the letter of the *current working directory*, the other the drive letter of the *drive where the file containing this code is on*. You can replace `process.cwd()` and `__dirname` with any absolute path to get the drive letter.

Second way:

```
import * as os from 'os';
import * as path from 'path';
const cwdOSRoot = os.platform() === 'win32' ? `${process.cwd().split(path.sep)[0]}:` : '/';
const fileOSRoot = os.platform() === 'win32' ? `${__dirname.split(path.sep)[0]}:` : '/';
```

Then just use `path.join`, `path.normalize`, `path.resolve` etc.. This code will work for any OS.